Select part of long text in form using VBA with MS Access 2019
in my form, on the bottom, I have the navigation bar to move between records. There is also a Search field which works pretty well but it's too small.
So I want to do my own version (or if someone knows how to use the same MS function).
Long text is a problem because I'm not able to select the search text in it (SetFocus, SelStart, SelLenght are not implemented but the MS version is working with this type of field).
Is there a solution ?
' Déclarez une variable globale pour mémoriser la position de la dernière recherche
Dim lngDernierIndex As Long

Private Sub btnRechercher_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strRecherche As String
    Dim strField As String
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim arrChamps() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim trouve As Boolean
    
    ' Récupérer la valeur saisie dans la zone de texte
    strRecherche = Me.txtRecherche.Value
    
    ' Initialisation du tableau de champs à rechercher (tableau de chaînes)
    arrChamps = Split("Description,NomCommun,NomScientifique,Cohabitation,Reproduction,Maladies,Dangers,Mutations,Classe,Ordre,Famille", ",")
    
    ' Initialisation du recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

    ' Si c'est la première recherche ou si la zone de recherche a changé, recommencer du début
    If Me.txtRecherche.Tag <> strRecherche Then
        lngDernierIndex = 0 ' Réinitialise l'index de recherche
        Me.txtRecherche.Tag = strRecherche ' Stocke le terme de recherche pour la prochaine recherche
    End If
    
    ' Si lngDernierIndex dépasse le nombre d'enregistrements, afficher un message
    If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Il n'y a aucun enregistrement dans cette base.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' S'assurer que lngDernierIndex ne dépasse pas la limite
    If lngDernierIndex >= rst.RecordCount Then
        MsgBox "Vous avez atteint la fin des enregistrements.", vbInformation
        lngDernierIndex = 0 ' Réinitialise l'index pour recommencer la recherche
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Positionner le curseur à l'emplacement du dernier enregistrement trouvé
    rst.AbsolutePosition = lngDernierIndex
    
    trouve = False
    Do Until rst.EOF
        ' Parcourir chaque champ pour trouver un match
        For i = LBound(arrChamps) To UBound(arrChamps)
            strField = arrChamps(i)
            
            ' Vérifier si le champ existe dans le jeu d'enregistrements avant de l'utiliser
            If FieldExists(rst, strField) Then
                ' Recherche d'un match dans le champ actuel
                If Not IsNull(rst(strField)) Then
                    lngStart = InStr(1, rst(strField).Value, strRecherche, vbTextCompare)
                    If lngStart > 0 Then
                        ' Déplacer le formulaire vers cet enregistrement
                        Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
                        
                        ' Vérifie le type du champ pour éviter les erreurs avec les champs "Texte long"
                        If TypeOf Me.Controls(strField) Is Access.TextBox Then
                            ' Si le champ est un TextBox standard
                            Me.Controls(strField).SetFocus
                            Me.Controls(strField).SelStart = lngStart - 1
                            Me.Controls(strField).SelLength = Len(strRecherche)
                        Else
                            ' Si le champ est un "Texte long", on ne fait rien ici
                            'MsgBox "Le champ '" & strField & "' est de type 'Texte long'.", vbInformation
                             ' Si le champ est un "Texte long", sélectionnez le texte dans ce contrôle
                            Me.Controls(strField).SelStart = lngStart - 1
                            Me.Controls(strField).SelLength = Len(strRecherche)
                        End If
                        
                        trouve = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        
        If trouve Then Exit Do
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    ' Si aucun enregistrement n'est trouvé
    If Not trouve Then
        MsgBox "Aucun autre enregistrement trouvé.", vbInformation
        lngDernierIndex = 0 ' Réinitialise la position si rien n'est trouvé
    Else
        ' Mémoriser la position du dernier enregistrement trouvé
        lngDernierIndex = rst.AbsolutePosition + 1
    End If
    
    ' Libérer le recordset
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub

' Fonction pour vérifier si un champ existe dans un Recordset
Function FieldExists(rst As DAO.Recordset, fieldName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FieldExists = (rst.Fields(fieldName).Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Thanks,
Vincent

To simulate the inbuilt Search, use DoCmd.FindRecord - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.findrecord

Oh thanks, I'll try this.
